# A question about finding the inverse of a function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, function-and-relation-composition

**Question:**

> $f : \mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ is defined by $f((x, y)) = (y, x)$. Write down whether $f^{-1}$ exists. If it does, write down $f^{-1}((3, 4))$. If it doesn’t, explain why not.

**Answer:** $f^{-1}((3, 4)) = (4, 3)$

So I can see that it meets the properties of being one-to-one and onto and that the composite of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ is equal to the composite of $f^{-1}$ and $f$.

But could I also argue that $f^{-1}(x,y) = (x,y)$ so that $f^{-1}(3,4) = (3,4)$?

In this case, the composite of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ would be $(4,3)$ and the composite of $f^{-1}$ and $f$ would also be $(4,3)$?

Comment: How could you argue that $f^{-1}((x,y)) = (x,y)$ for all $x,y$?

Comment: So... if $f$ "swaps the inputs"... we want $f^{-1}$ to undo this operation.  Kind of like how for the function $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ given as $g(x)=2x$ one would have $g$ "doubles the input", we would want $g^{-1}$ to undo that operation.  In the case of my example of $g(x)=2x$, to "undo" the operation of "doubling the input" one would instead "halve" the input... i.e. $g^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}x$.  So... how does one "undo" the operation of "swapping" the first two inputs?  (*Think about what happens if you swap twice in succession*)

Comment: ok that makes a lot of sense, thanks JMoravitz.

Comment: Remember... given a function $f:X\to Y$, the functional inverse (*assuming one exists*) is the unique function $f^{-1}:Y\to X$ such that $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in X$ and that $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ for all $y\in Y$ (*keeping in mind that the inputs and outputs are elements of the domain and codomain respectively.  These could be tuples or triples or matrices or whatever type of object it happens to be for that example, e.g. pairs of numbers in yours*). Note, specifically that $(f\circ g)=(g\circ f)$ is neither necessary nor sufficient in proving that a $g$ is the functional inverse of $f$...

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x,y)$ 1-1 and onto (bijective) an inverse exits.

Note that $(f\circ f)(x,y) = f(y,x) = (x,y)$

$f^{-1}(x,y) = f(x,y)$